# Deciding between: dojo, backbone.js, knockout.js (or other) for Rails 3.1 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, dojo, backbone.js, knockout.js

We have an existing Rails 3.1 consumer-facing web app and are reworking the UI to be far more interactive, snappy, app-like.

We have a modestly complex data model, but there's only a modest need for form-based user input.

We use jQuery now, with plugins to do nice effects, but overall, our JS skills are weak.

Our primary objective is to find a framework that helps us structure and organize our JS code and simplify the cases where we do have data bindings, AJAX, etc. in our Rails 3.1 world.

We'll learn how to do JS properly, but while we do, is there a clear framework we could learn and work within?

Comment: Dojo is a more batteries-included framework. Backbone and knockout are just for the MVC parts, IIRC...

Comment: Very subjective. But if you like MVVM, knockout will seem very familiar. If you want something leaner, Backbone is nice.  It [works well with rails](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-rails), but then, the others probably do as well.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't know Dojo, but Backbone vs Knockout is a bit like comparing apples to oranges.

Backbone provides a structure for a web application + synchronization with the backend, whereas Knockout drives UI updates. There *is* some overlap between the two, but it doesn't mean they are actual competitors. There is even a project that tries to combine both - [Knockback](https://github.com/kmalakoff/knockback).

Last but not least, there is a great discussion on [Bb vs Ko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112899/knockout-js-vs-backbone-js-vs).

**EDIT:** I've just found this: http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/ - a comparison of different approaches to creating the same TODO app.

Comment: Thanks for the comparison -- very helpful.  But I am increasingly getting the feeling that the glue that makes Rails so excellent isn't there yet with either backbone.js or knockout.js -- the backbone-rails gem looks promising (good and opinionated about where stuff goes!) and deals with the 3.1 asset pipeline features.  Many existing demos are badly out of date.

Comment: Since you mentioned Knockback, maybe you can help me out with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992431/using-knockoutjs-backbone-together

Comment: Do you have any experience with Knockback?

Comment: @Mihai: Not really, except that I know it exists

Comment: That Bb vs Ko link is broken.

Comment: @Knownasilya: Hmm, has it been removed? It was definitely a real question with real answers

Comment: @Knownasilya: The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112899/knockout-js-vs-backbone-js link works now.

Comment: Consider DOJO for:
Organisation: Code in DOJO can be created using AMD, which allow to modularise your app.
DIJIT provides quality widgets  (you can easily write you own widgets). You can also use MVC paradigm in DOJO.

Ajax: You can use Dojo for making requests to a server. It has support for Promises/Deferreds which can help you to communication between asynchronous threads.

Also interesting:
The dojo/aspect module provides AOP facilities to attach additional functionality to existing methods.
dojo/topic which allow you to use Publish–subscribe for communication between modules in your app.